# Ansible scp/copy over ssh

Tags: ssh, ansible, scp

Trying some stuff out with Ansible but it seems doing a simple scp is not something trivial.

I checked modules:
synchronize, copy, fetch.

These either don't seem to have specifiers for the source host or are not using an ssh tunnel (scp, rsync+ssh).

What I'm trying to do is very simple:
scp remotehost:/path/file /tmp/file

With the latter being the host(s) to be configured.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Check out example from the [docs](http://docs.ansible.com/ansible/synchronize_module.html): `synchronize: mode=pull src=rsync://somehost.com/path/ dest=/some/absolute/path/`

Comment: See here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25505146/how-to-copy-files-between-two-nodes-using-ansible Note: `rysnc` is required on hosts + `delegate_to`

Comment: Thanks for the responses. I had tried the synchronize above. But that didn't seem to work. In my case the remote where I pull the file from is a FreeBSD machine so in the end I kept it simple and used raw to do the copy.

Comment: could you provide some specific error messages?