# Ansible: How to copy files remote to remote

Tags: ansible

I need to copy file `/etc/resolv.conf` from a remote host and copy it on multiple remote hosts.

```
my hosts:
Ansible
ubuntu1-4
```

I want to copy this file from `ubuntu1` to `ubuntu2`, `ubuntu3` and `ubuntu4` 
I tried the `synchronize` module but I can't/don't want to use `rsync` as a demon on `ubuntu1-4`.

Is there a better way than copying it on Ansible and from Ansible to `ubuntu2` till `4`?

Comment: Duplicate https://stackoverflow.com/q/25505146/2947502

Comment: yes i know this link, but they use synchronize.

Comment: It doesn't change the fact that this is the method to do it. Ansible was not written to copy files between target machines. synchronize module is already an exception (breaching concepts) in Ansible modules.　And even assuming someone has written another one with the same functionality as `synchronize`, that answer should be posted under that other question, not here. This one should be closed, but I ran out of closed votes for today.

Comment: The title of this one is misleading for ansible "remote to remote" in this context is on the same host. As such if a new user is searching for "copy files remote to remote" they will get this when they are really after
`
 tasks:
    - copy:
        src: /home/resolv.conf
        dest: /etc/resolv.conf
        remote_src: yes
`
Please consider changing the title to something like "Ansible: How to copy files between remote hosts" or "Ansible: How to synchronize files between remote hosts"

Answer (score 12, accepted):

If you're just talking about a single file you don't need the `synchronize` module.  You can grab a file from a remote host using the [`fetch`](http://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/fetch_module.html) module.  Once you have the file on your local system, you can just use the `copy` module to distribute it to other hosts.

Something like:

```yaml
- hosts: ubuntu1
  tasks:
    - fetch:
        src: /etc/resolv.conf
        dest: ./resolv.conf
        flat: true

- hosts: all:!ubuntu1
  tasks:
    - copy:
        src: ./resolv.conf
        dest: /etc/resolv.conf
```

While this works, a better solution would be to maintain the appropriate `resolv.conf` as part of your ansible configuration and distribute it to *all* hosts, rather than copying it from one remote to others.

Comment: @MichallKo How does it meet the requirement you specified "*There is better way than copy it on Ansible and from Ansible to ubuntu2-4?*"?

Comment: This isn't the answer for "remote to remote". This is an answer for "remote to host to remote". It may gave worked for OP, but he or she asked the wrong question.

Comment: thanks, this is exactly what I was looking for, i prefer ansible to do the copying rather than opening ssh between hosts

Comment: @NicholasMartinez This is still remote to remote, but through the controller. A true remote to remote copy would require setting up ssh access between the remote hosts and is not desirable, especially if it is needed for this purpose alone. It may actually be possible to copy over an ad-hoc port (e.g., using rsync or netcat), but corporate environments usually have ACLs restricting ports, so this should be the most reliable method.

Answer (score 1):

In case, you want to copy a file from remote to the ansible control node - we can use the **ansible fetch** module.
This works both for Linux and windows machine.