# Synchronize files/folders between two remote hosts

Tags: ansible

I have two web servers behind a load balancer that use Let's Encrypt for automatic SSL. `web1` will handle the creation and renewal of the SSL keys and then synchronize those keys onto `web2`. Trying to use a [variant of this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25505146/how-to-copy-files-between-two-nodes-using-ansible) isn't working for me:

```
- name: Sync SSL files from master to slave(s)
  synchronize:
    src: "{{ item }}"
    dest: "{{ item }}"
  when: inventory_hostname != 'web1'
  delegate_to: web1
  with_items:
    - /etc/nginx/ssl/letsencrypt/
    - /var/lib/letsencrypt/csrs/
    - /var/lib/letsencrypt/account.key
    - /etc/ssl/certs/lets-encrypt-x3-cross-signed.pem
```

That returns an immediate error of:

```
Permission denied (publickey).\r\nrsync: connection unexpectedly closed (0 bytes received so far) [Receiver]\nrsync error: unexplained error (code 255) at io.c(605) [Receiver=3.0.9]\n"
```

Why isn't the ssh forwarding working once ansible logs into `web1` or `web2`? When I execute this manually, it works fine:

```
ssh -A user@web1
#logged into web1 successfully
ssh user@web2
#logged into web2 successfully
```

Here is my `ansible.cfg`

```
[defaults]
filter_plugins = ~/.ansible/plugins/filter_plugins/:/usr/share/ansible_plugins/filter_plugins:lib/trellis/plugins/filter
host_key_checking = False
force_color = True
force_handlers = True
inventory = hosts
nocows = 1
roles_path = vendor/roles

[ssh_connection]
ssh_args=-o ControlMaster=auto -o ControlPersist=60s -o ControlPath=/tmp/ansible-ssh-%h-%p-%r -o ForwardAgent=yes
pipelining = True
retries = 1
```

What I think is happening is I am trying to copy contents from a folder with root only permissions. So `sudo` is being used, which switches my user and why I get a permission denied, b/c the SSH key is associated with non-root. So it seems I need a way to access contents of a root only folder and send it across with a regular user. I might create a few steps to copy and change permissions with root, then sync with non-root, and use sudo to fix permissions on the remote host.

Seems like a lot of steps, but not sure if synchronize can handle my use case.

**UPDATED**: Added more relevant error

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to copy files between two nodes using ansible](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25505146/how-to-copy-files-between-two-nodes-using-ansible)

Comment: Your error is `src: "rsync://…"`. With this, the rsync command is executed on `web1`, but still has a remote source (from there), which isn't necessary.
If you set `src: "{{item}}"`, it should work.

Comment: Now I get this error: `Permission denied (publickey).\r\nrsync: connection unexpectedly closed (0 bytes received so far)`. I can manually ssh from `web1` to `web2` and the other way around. As long as I initially allow ssh forwarding with `ssh -a user@web1`. How can I force that with ansible?

Comment: https://www.calazan.com/using-ssh-agent-forwarding-with-ansible/

Comment: @YSelf updated my answer with my current ansible.cfg & error.