# synchronize module in Ansible for copying files on remote hosts

Tags: linux, ansible, centos7, ansible-inventory

I am trying to set-up a simple Ansible playbook to carry out copying files from one location to another location on the same remote host. My local, as well as remote hosts, run CentOS-7.

This is how my inventory file looks like:

```
centos-server ansible_host=10.1.1.1 ansible_connection=ssh ansible_user=root ansible_ssh_pass=<root password>
```

I used the copy module initially, however, found that this module only copies a file from local to remote. After a bit of search, I found [synchronize](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35742157/3559105) module which seems to be the correct one to use.

My simple playbook is as follows:

```
-
  name: sync upstream repository to the local machine
  hosts: centos-server
  tasks:
    -
      name: copy repo files to yum.repos
      synchronize:
        src: /etc/yum.repos.d/repo.backup/
        dest: /etc/yum.repos.d/
      delegate_to: centos-server
```

As can be seen, I have some `.repo` files in the source directory and trying to copy them to `yum.repos.d` directory. The above playbook works without any issues, however, I do need to specify `delegate_to` attribute.

As per the example discussed in [synchronize](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35742157/3559105), I understand the `delegate_to` is required as the file is copied from a remote host that is not defined in `hosts:`. While in my case, both source and destination are on the same remote host defined in `hosts:`. Without `delegate_to`, I get this error:

```
fatal: [centos-server]: FAILED! => {"changed": false, "cmd": "/bin/rsync --delay-updates -F --compress --dry-run --archive --rsh=/bin/ssh -S none -o StrictHostKeyChecking=no -o UserKnownHostsFile=/dev/null --out-format=<<CHANGED>>%i %n%L /etc/yum.repos.d/repo.backup/ root@10.1.1.1:/etc/yum.repos.d/", "msg": "Warning: Permanently added '10.1.1.1' (ECDSA) to the list of known hosts.\r\nrsync: change_dir \"/etc/yum.repos.d/repo.backup\" failed: No such file or directory (2)\nrsync error: some files/attrs were not transferred (see previous errors) (code 23) at main.c(1052) [sender=3.0.9]\n", "rc": 23}
```

Can anyone explain what could be happening here?

Comment: Syncronise uses rsync to copy files. You have an error in the rsync command generated by Ansible: No such file or directory (2)

Answer (score -2):

You can set the *remote_src* option to copy files on the remote machine with the copy command:

```
# Example from ansible docs
# Copy a "sudoers" file on the remote machine for editing
- copy:
    src: /etc/sudoers
    dest: /etc/sudoers.edit
    remote_src: yes
    validate: /usr/sbin/visudo -cf %s
```

See: http://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/copy_module.html#options

Comment: The copy `module` with `remote_src` attribute, unfortunately, doesn't recursively copy files.