# How to synchronize a file between two remote servers in Ansible?

Tags: ansible, synchronize

The end goal is for me to copy `file.txt` from `Host2` over to `Host1`. However, I keep getting the same error whenever I perform the function. I have triple checked my spacing and made sure I spelled everything correctly, but nothing seems to work.

**Command to start the playbook:**

```
ansible-playbook playbook_name.yml -i inventory/inventory_name -u username -k
```

**My Code:**

```
- hosts: Host1
  tasks: 


  - name: Synchronization using rsync protocol on delegate host (pull)
    synchronize:
        mode: pull
        src: rsync://Host2.linux.us.com/tmp/file.txt
        dest: /tmp
    delegate_to: Host2.linux.us.com
```

**Expected Result:**

```
Successfully working
```

**Actual Result:**

```
fatal: [Host1.linux.us.com]: FAILED! => {"changed": false, "cmd": "sshpass", "msg": "[Errno 2] No such file or directory", "rc": 2}
```

Comment: you are trying to copy from host2 to host1. in that case, you don't need mode: pull. remove the mode: pull and give a try

Comment: this question has been answered in multiple cases. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25505146/how-to-copy-files-between-two-nodes-using-ansible

Answer (score 2):

I have the same problem as you，Installing sshpass on the target host can work normally
`yum install -y sshpass`

Comment: Add some explanation about solution. Thanks

Comment: I also encountered the same issue. After installing sshpass, I'm able to run synchronize module playbook.