# What is the meaning of `delegate_to` in ansible task?

Tags: ansible

As I understand every ansible task is executed in context of some host. Let's call it "remote host".

For some ansible modules (f.e. `fetch` and `copy`) two hosts are involved: the "remote host" and the host where the ansible script is running (let's call it "local host").

Let's say we want to copy a file between two different remote hosts. [How to copy files between two nodes using ansible](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25505146) suggests the following solution:

```
- hosts: ServerB
  tasks:
    - name: Transfer file from ServerA to ServerB
      synchronize:
        src: /path/on/server_a
        dest: /path/on/server_b
      delegate_to: ServerA
```

Looks like the effect of `delegate_to` in this case is that the task still runs in context of ServerB (remote host), but instead of local host the host specified by `delegate_to` is used (ServerA in this case).

But the behavior is quite different in the following case:

```
- hosts: ServerB
  tasks:
  - name: Copy file from local host to Server A
    copy:
      src: /local/path
      dest: /path/on/server_a
    delegate_to: ServerA
```

Even though values of `hosts` and `delegate_to` are the same in previous case, the copy operation happens between the local host and the host specified by `delegate_to`. So in this case `delegate_to` modifies not the local host, but remote host.

Why the behavior of `delegate_to` is different in these cases? Is it module-specific? But this parameter is not mentioned in ansible documentation of `synchronize` and `copy` modules, so I expected it's behavior should be the same for all modules.

Comment: `synchronize` is a little special in this context. [Read the doc page of the module](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/modules/synchronize_module.html) to understand how it handles the option. In the most general case, `delegate_to` simply means "Use facts from the current play host (unless you also used `deletegate_facts`....) and play that module on this other host instead of the current play host".

Comment: PS: you probably want to read this as well: https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/user_guide/playbooks_delegation.html