# How do I use ansible to scp from a specfic host not in enventory to hosts in inventory?

Tags: ansible, fetch, scp, ansible-inventory, inventory

I need to have my ansible playbook to pull a file via scp to each host in inventory from a host not in inventory.

In my example I am running my playbook from `10.3.3.10`

my inventory:

```
[linux]
10.2.2.10
10.2.2.11
10.2.2.12
```

Here is an example command of what I want to run on each host.

```
scp admin@10.10.10.100:/backup/scripts/special_script /root
```

I cant seem to find a way to accomplish this with `fetch` outside of just running `shell` and using the scp command as is.

Is there a way to accomplish this with fetch, or a built in idempotent method?

Comment: For sure having an initial play in your playbook that targets the 10.10.100 host to pull that file back to the controller to make it available for the next play(s) to use. The trick is going to be that your `scp` command likely uses _your_ ssh to authenticate `admin` and in order to make the play useful you'll need to teach _ansible_ how to do that same

Comment: You can [sync](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61720113/sync-files-between-2-hosts-using-ansible/61722159#61722159) whatever you want If the hosts can *ssh* each other and you can install *rsync* on them. The next limitation might by Python. The source must by an Ansible client.

Answer (score 2):

Q: ***Is there a way to accomplish this ... in idempotent method?"***

A: Yes. You can make the [*command*](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/collections/ansible/builtin/command_module.html) idempotent by using the parameter [*creates*](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/collections/ansible/builtin/command_module.html#parameter-creates). Quoting:

> If a matching file already exists, this step will not be run.

```yaml
- command:
    cmd: scp admin@10.10.10.100:script /root
    creates: /root/script
```

---

There are many other options depending on the bandwidth, file size, and environment. See [Ansible - fetch files from one remote node to another](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/734647/ansible-fetch-files-from-one-remote-node-to-another/734712#734712)

- If you can install Ansible on 10.10.10.100 the trivial option would be to run a play there.
- It's also possible to create a script to rsync the files from the command line on 10.10.10.100
- Get the file on the controller first.

Comment: but what if there's a difference in the file contents? wouldn't a certain check on the hash of the file be better?

Comment: You can use *rsync*.