# Ansible Tower - How to copy files from Remote Linux Server1 going to Remote Linux Server2

Tags: ansible, ansible-tower

Hi I have an Ansible Tower.

I want my playbook to run in Ansible Tower and do:
Copy files from a Remote Linux Server 1 going to a Remote Linux Server 2.

I tried modules: Copy and Fetch but seems like the playbook behave differently when running in Ansible Tower.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to copy files between two nodes using ansible](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25505146/how-to-copy-files-between-two-nodes-using-ansible)

Answer (score 1):

Regarding

> *... the playbook behave differently when running in Ansible Tower ...*

I haven't made such experience since Ansible Tower is just a web front end to Ansible Engine and as far as I understand.

> *Copy files from a Remote Linux Server 1 going to a Remote Linux Server 2.*

In such case the [`synchronize`_module](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/collections/ansible/posix/synchronize_module.html) might be the solution. For database replication setup I use a construct like

```yaml
- name: Synchronize file from primary to secondary
  synchronize:
    src: "/tmp/file.tar.gz"
    dest: "/tmp/file.tar.gz"
    mode: push
  delegate_to: "{{ PRIMARY_HOST }}"
  when: "{{ SECONDARY_HOST }}"
  tags: replication,rsync
```

which is "copying" a file from the primary node to the secondary node. There are also a lot of answers under [How to copy files between two nodes using Ansible](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25505146/).