# How to synchronize a list of files from one Windows Remote Server to another via Ansible?

Tags: ansible, ansible-2.x, file-transfer, ansible-template

I am currently trying to transmit a list of files from one Windows Remote Server to another Windows Remote Server initiated from a third Linux Control Machine.

My current implementation is as follows but Ansible appears to be unable to receive the values for `src` and `dest` within my loop. Please note the path to the files is the same on both the source and destination servers.

```yaml
- name: file transfer playbook template
  hosts: destination_host

  vars:

    files:
      - '\path\to\file1'
      - '\path\to\file2'
      - '\path\to\file3'

  tasks:

    - name: transfer files from one remote host to another
      synchronize:
        src: "{{ item }}"
        dest: "{{ item }}"
      delegate_to: "{{ source_host }}"
      loop: "{{ files }}"
```

The value for `source_host` is sent from the extra vars section of Ansible Tower.

```yaml
source_host: <SOURCE SERVER NAME>
```

When this template is run the following error is returned

```json
PLAY [file transfer playbook template] ************************

TASK [transfer files from one remote host to another] *********
 [started TASK: transfer files from one remote host to another on <SOURCE SERVER NAME>]
failed: [<SOURCE SERVER NAME> -> <DESTINATION SERVER NAME>] (item=None) => {"ansible_loop_var": "item", "changed": false, "item": null, "msg": "synchronize requires both src and dest parameters are set"}

PLAY RECAP ****************************************************
```

My question is pretty similar to [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/a/69484599/6771046) and [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25505146/how-can-i-copy-files-between-two-managed-nodes-using-ansible), however mine differs as I am trying to send a list of defined files with a loop wrapping around my synchronization task which is where I believe my issue is arising.

Comment: `"item": null` is the reason. Take a look at the list `files`.

Comment: Hey @VladimirBotka, thanks for your response. Is there an issue with how I declared my list? Apologies I am pretty new to ansible and am having some difficulties seeing what's wrong with my declaration?

Comment: I don't know which list you're talking about. [edit] the question and make it [mre]. Then we would probably know.

Comment: https://idownvotedbecau.se/nomcve and asked to close.

Comment: Hey @VladimirBotka, I was referring to the ```files``` list you mentioned in your first comment. I have included all of my relevant code but I will add an edit to show how I pass ```source_host``` through Ansible tower (maybe my initial description wasn't clear enough on this). I masked the file paths and server names, but I feel like me placing the actual values of these doesn't add more context to my error.

I read through the links you posted and am genuinely unsure of what I did wrong :(

Comment: Does this answer your question: [How to copy files from Remote Linux Server1 going to Remote Linux Server2](https://stackoverflow.com/a/69484599/6771046)?

Comment: Thank you @U880D, unfortunately my use case is slightly different since I have a list of files to transmit rather than just one file. I believe I need to nest my code within a loop as an additional step to correct this which is seemingly where my issue is arising from.

Comment: "_unfortunately my use case is slightly different since I have a list of files to transmit rather than just one file_", why do you think so? Have you tested the given example with a list?

Answer (score 1):

Based on the already mentioned "*[How to copy files from Remote Linux Server1 going to Remote Linux Server2?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/69484599/6771046)*", I am not able to reproduce an issue with a list of files between Linux Remote Nodes.

A minimal example playbook

```yaml
---
- hosts: test
  become: false
  gather_facts: false

  vars:

    FILES:
      - /tmp/test.file
      - /tmp/test.file

  tasks:

  - name: Synchronize file from primary to secondary
    synchronize:
      src: "{{ item }}"
      dest: "{{ item }}"
      mode: push
    delegate_to: primary.example.com
    when: inventory_hostname == 'secondary.example.com'
    loop: "{{ FILES }}"
```

will result into the expected output of

```yaml
TASK [Synchronize file from primary to secondary] *****************************
changed: [secondary.example.com -> primary.eample.com] => (item=/tmp/test.file)
ok: [secondary.example.com -> primary.example.com] => (item=/tmp/test.file)
```

---

After editing I've notice that it is a **Use Case regarding Windows Remote Nodes**.

Whereby the

- [`synchronize` module (is) A wrapper around Linux `rsync`](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/collections/ansible/posix/synchronize_module.html)

for Windows Nodes you may use

- [`win_robocopy` module – Synchronizes the contents of two directories using `robocopy`](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/collections/community/windows/win_robocopy_module.html)
- or the [`win_copy` module (in order to) Copy files to remote locations on Windows Hosts](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/collections/ansible/windows/win_copy_module.html)

Another dependencies which is hit in such case is, that the `synchronize` task will just drop the backslashes `\`, resulting into a path of `tmptest.file` in this example here.

```yaml
TASK [Synchronize file from primary to secondary] *******************************************************************
failed: [secondary.example.com -> primary.example.com] (item=\tmp\test.file) => changed=false
  ansible_loop_var: item
...
  item: \tmp\test.file
  msg: |-
...
    rsync: link_stat "/home/user/test/tmptest.file" failed: No such file or directory (2)
    rsync error: some files/attrs were not transferred (see previous errors) (code 23) at main.c(1179) [sender=3.1.2]
  rc: 23
...
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer U880D, I have been trying to get this to work with the win_robocopy and win_copy modules, however neither has baked in functionalities for remote-remote communication. I have implemented a playbook that fetches from a Windows remote then uses the win_copy module to push to the other Windows remote; while this works fine for a couple of files it has become a mess when trying to set it up for multiple files with differing paths - especially since fetch requires forward slashed paths and win_copy uses back slashed paths.