# Ansible synchronize files among remote hosts

Tags: ansible, rsync

I have three VMs for example. VM.A is the Ansible controller, VM.B is remote server 1 and VM.C is remote server 2.

I want to be able to transfer files from VM.B to VM.C using the *synchronize* module in Ansible as it rules out the need for a /tmp directory on the Ansible controller.

Below is an example yaml. But the trouble is, the Ansible controller can ssh to both VM.B and VM.C, but does VM.B need to be able to ssh to VM.C? At the moment the code doesn't work.

```yaml
- name: Copy File Between Remote Servers
  hosts: source_servers
  become: yes  # If needed, to gain privileges for reading source file
  tasks:
    - name: Synchronize file to the destination server
      synchronize:
        src: /path/to/source/file
        dest: /path/on/destination/server/file
      delegate_to: "{{ groups['destination_servers'][0] }}"  # Choose the first server from the destination group
      become: yes  # If needed, to gain privileges for writing to the destination path
```

Answer (score 0):

Context: The host *vm_a* is an Ansible controller. Transfer files from the host *vm_b* to host *vm_c* using the *synchronize* module.

Q: ***"Does *vm_b* need to be able to ssh to *vm_c*?"***

A: Yes. Quoting from the [Notes](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/collections/ansible/posix/synchronize_module.html#notes):

> Only a few connection types support *synchronize* (ssh, paramiko, local, and docker) because a sync strategy has been determined for those connection types.

You'll have to decide how to declare the workflow. For example, create a dictionary of the sources that should be synchronized to targets

```yaml
  sync:
    vm_b: [vm_c]
```

Then, the task below should do the job

```yaml
    - name: Synchronize files
      synchronize:
        mode: pull
        src: /tmp/test/
        dest: /tmp/test/
        recursive: true
      delegate_to: "{{ item }}"
      loop: "{{ sync[inventory_hostname] }}"
      when: inventory_hostname in sync
```

---

Note: Instead of the condition you can set an empty list by default

```yaml
      loop: "{{ sync[inventory_hostname]|d([]) }}"
```

---

**Example of a complete project for testing**

Given the inventory

```ini
shell> cat hosts
[source_servers]
vm_b ansible_host=10.1.0.10
vm_c ansible_host=10.1.0.17

[source_servers:vars]
ansible_connection=ssh
ansible_user=admin
```

Synchronize the files on the host *vm_b* (10.1.0.10)

```bash
shell> ssh admin@10.1.0.10 ls -la /tmp/test/
total 8
drwxr-xr-x   2 admin  wheel   512 Aug 10 21:17 .
drwxrwxrwt  32 root   wheel  3072 Aug 10 21:23 ..
-rw-r--r--   1 admin  wheel     0 Aug 10 19:51 file_1
-rw-r--r--   1 admin  wheel     0 Aug 10 19:51 file_2
-rw-r--r--   1 admin  wheel     0 Aug 10 19:51 file_3
```

to the host *vm_c* (10.1.0.17)

```bash
shell> ssh admin@10.1.0.17 ls -la /tmp/test/
total 8
drwxr-xr-x   2 admin  wheel   512 Aug 10 21:23 .
drwxrwxrwt  27 root   wheel  3072 Aug 10 21:24 ..
```

1. **Distribute the public keys**

- Declare the below variables

```yaml
    sync:
      vm_b: [vm_c]
    admin: admin
    keys_dir: /tmp/ansible/keys
    targets: "{{ sync.values()|flatten|unique }}"
```

- Create a dictionary on the controller to store the public keys

```yaml
    - name: Create keys_dir
      file:
        state: directory
        dest: "{{ keys_dir }}"
      delegate_to: localhost
```

- Get the public keys of the targets. The target host will ssh the source hosts and **pull** the files via *rsync*

```yaml
    - name: Get keys
      block:
        - user:
            name: "{{ admin }}"
            generate_ssh_key: true
        - fetch:
            src: "/home/{{ admin }}/.ssh/id_rsa.pub"
            dest: "{{ keys_dir }}"
      when: inventory_hostname in targets
```

- Distribute the keys to the sources

```yaml
    - name: Distribute keys
      authorized_key:
        user: "{{ admin }}"
        key: "{{ lookup('file', key_file) }}"
      loop: "{{ sync[inventory_hostname]|d([]) }}"
      vars:
        key_file: "{{ keys_dir }}/{{ item }}/home/{{ admin }}/.ssh/id_rsa.pub"
      become: true
```

2. **Synchronize the files**

- List the files

```yaml
    - name: List files
      block:
        - command: ls -1 /tmp/test
          register: out
        - debug:
            var: out.stdout
```

gives

```yaml
ok: [vm_b] => 
  out.stdout: |-
    file_1
    file_2
    file_3
ok: [vm_c] => 
  out.stdout: ''
```

- Synchronize the files

```yaml
    - name: Synchronize files
      synchronize:
        mode: pull
        src: /tmp/test/
        dest: /tmp/test/
        recursive: true
      delegate_to: "{{ item }}"
      loop: "{{ sync[inventory_hostname] }}"
      when: inventory_hostname in sync
```

gives (running with options --check --diff)

```yaml
skipping: [vm_c]
.d..t....... ./
>f++++++++++ file_1
>f++++++++++ file_2
>f++++++++++ file_3
changed: [vm_b -> vm_c(10.1.0.17)] => (item=vm_c)
```

**Example of a complete playbook**

```yaml
- hosts: source_servers

  vars:

    sync:
      vm_b: [vm_c]
    admin: admin
    keys_dir: /tmp/ansible/keys
    targets: "{{ sync.values()|flatten|unique }}"

  tasks:

    - debug:
        msg: |
          admin: {{ admin }}
          keys_dir: {{ keys_dir }}
          targets: {{ targets }}
          sync:
            {{ sync|to_yaml(indent=2)|indent(2) }}
      when: debug|d(false)|bool
      run_once: true
      tags: debug

    - name: Create keys_dir
      file:
        state: directory
        dest: "{{ keys_dir }}"
      delegate_to: localhost
      run_once: true
      tags: dir

    - name: Get keys
      block:
        - user:
            name: "{{ admin }}"
            generate_ssh_key: true
        - fetch:
            src: "/home/{{ admin }}/.ssh/id_rsa.pub"
            dest: "{{ keys_dir }}"
      when: inventory_hostname in targets
      tags: keys_get

    - name: Distribute keys test
      debug:
        msg: >-
          Copy {{ keys_dir }}/{{ item }}/home/{{ admin }}/.ssh/id_rsa
          to {{ admin }}@{{ inventory_hostname }}
      loop: "{{ sync[inventory_hostname]|d([]) }}"
      tags: keys_distribute_test

    - name: Distribute keys
      authorized_key:
        user: "{{ admin }}"
        key: "{{ lookup('file', key_file) }}"
      loop: "{{ sync[inventory_hostname]|d([]) }}"
      vars:
        key_file: "{{ keys_dir }}/{{ item }}/home/{{ admin }}/.ssh/id_rsa.pub"
      become: true
      tags: keys_distribute

    - name: List files
      block:
        - command: ls -1 /tmp/test
          register: out
        - debug:
            var: out.stdout
      tags: list

    - name: Synchronize files
      synchronize:
        mode: pull
        src: /tmp/test/
        dest: /tmp/test/
        recursive: true
      delegate_to: "{{ item }}"
      loop: "{{ sync[inventory_hostname] }}"
      when: inventory_hostname in sync
      tags: sync
```

---

**Escalation**

If you set the escalation of the privileges for the remote user on the target, for example, in the inventory

```ini
shell> cat hosts
[source_servers]
vm_b ansible_host=10.1.0.10
vm_c ansible_host=10.1.0.17 ansible_become=true

[source_servers:vars]
ansible_connection=ssh
ansible_user=admin
```

the synchronization will fail

> failed: [vm_b -> vm_c(10.1.0.17)] (item=vm_c) => changed=false
> ansible_loop_var: item
> cmd: /usr/local/bin/rsync --delay-updates -F --compress --archive --rsh='/usr/bin/ssh -S none -o StrictHostKeyChecking=no -o UserKnownHostsFile=/dev/null' --rsync-path='sudo -u root rsync' --out-format='<>%i %n%L' admin@10.1.0.10:/tmp/test/ /tmp/test/
> item: vm_c
> msg: |-
> Warning: Permanently added '10.1.0.10' (ECDSA) to the list of known hosts.
> admin@10.1.0.10: Permission denied (publickey).
> rsync: connection unexpectedly closed (0 bytes received so far) [Receiver]
> rsync error: error in rsync protocol data stream (code 12) at io.c(228) [Receiver=3.2.3]
> rc: 12

The same will happen when you set `become: true` in the playbook

```yaml
- hosts: source_servers
  become: true

  ...
```

, or in the task

```yaml
    - name: Synchronize files
      synchronize:
        mode: pull
        src: /tmp/test/
        dest: /tmp/test/
        recursive: true
      delegate_to: "{{ item }}"
      loop: "{{ sync[inventory_hostname]|d([]) }}"
      become: true
```

To escalate the privileges you have to allow root at the target to ssh to the source. This means, in the above example of the playbook, you have to fetch the root public keys from the targets

```yaml
    - name: Get keys
      block:
        - user:
            name: root
            generate_ssh_key: true
        - fetch:
            src: "/root/.ssh/id_rsa.pub"
            dest: "{{ keys_dir }}"
      when: inventory_hostname in targets
      become: true
```

and distribute them to the sources (task 'Distribute keys')

```yaml
      vars:
        key_file: "{{ keys_dir }}/{{ item }}/root/.ssh/id_rsa.pub"
```

Answer (score 0):

> *I want to be able to transfer files from VM.B to VM.C using the `synchronize` module.*

A construct like

```yaml
- name: Synchronize file from primary to secondary
  synchronize:
    src: "/tmp/file.tar.gz"
    dest: "/tmp/file.tar.gz"
    mode: push
  delegate_to: "{{ VM.B }}"
  when: "{{ VM.C }}"
```

is "copying" a file from VM.B to VM.C. Such I am using for replicating databases.

> *Does VM.B need to be able to SSH to VM.C?*

Since you are going to connect between the two Remote Managed Nodes, yes. See also [Delegating tasks](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/playbook_guide/playbooks_delegation.html#delegating-tasks).

**Similar Q&A**

> *VM.B is Remote Server 1 and VM.C is Remote Server 2.*

- [How to copy files from Remote Linux Server1 going to Remote Linux Server2?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/69484599/6771046)