# Ansible synchronize module - how to identify actual issue

Tags: synchronization, rsync, ansible-2.x

I have an Ansible playbook ( Ansible version 2.9.27 ) that uses the synchronize module to take backup of files.  This playbook is for taking backup of various confluent properties and other info from various confluent components.

The playbook runs successfully in one environment but asks for password in the other and basically hangs.

I have used the `ansible -i hosts.yml all -m ping` to verify passwordless ssh set-up for the targets and that runs successfully.

I have checked the rsync version in both the environments and it is the same version in both the places -

```
rsync  version 3.1.2  protocol version 31
Copyright (C) 1996-2015 by Andrew Tridgell, Wayne Davison, and others.
Web site: http://rsync.samba.org/
Capabilities:
    64-bit files, 64-bit inums, 64-bit timestamps, 64-bit long ints,
    socketpairs, hardlinks, symlinks, IPv6, batchfiles, inplace,
    append, ACLs, xattrs, iconv, symtimes, prealloc

rsync comes with ABSOLUTELY NO WARRANTY.  This is free software, and you
are welcome to redistribute it under certain conditions.  See the GNU
General Public Licence for details.
```

This is the playbook

---

```
- name:  Backup properties files, masterkey and passphrase fils and iverride.conf files as well as data from zookeeper 

  hosts: all

  tasks:

    - name : get the timestamp once
      set_fact:
        backupts: "{{lookup('pipe','date +%Y%m%d-%H%M%S')}}"
      run_once: true
      delegate_to: localhost

    - debug: 
        msg: "backupts:  ->  {{ backupts }}"
      run_once: true
      delegate_to: localhost

#   Ultimately set the inv_host_path variable to /software/scripts/confl-backup-5.5.1
    - name: set other facts
      set_fact:
        inv_host_path: "/tmp/backup"

    - name: Download /etc/.
      #https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25505146/how-to-copy-files-between-two-nodes-using-ansible
      synchronize:
        src: "/etc/{{ item }}"
        dest: "{{ inv_host_path }}/etc/"
        rsync_path: "sudo rsync"
        mode: pull
      with_items:
        - kafka
        - confluent*
      delegate_to: localhost
      register: etc_output
```

This is the output.

```
TASK [Gathering Facts] ******************************************************************************************************************************************************************************
ok: [server1.company.com]
ok: [server2.company.com]

TASK [get the timestamp once] ***********************************************************************************************************************************************************************
ok: [server1.company.com -> localhost]

TASK [debug] ****************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************
ok: [server1.company.com -> localhost] => {
    "msg": "backupts:  ->  20230308-070355"
}

TASK [set other facts] ******************************************************************************************************************************************************************************
ok: [server1.company.com]
ok: [server2.company.com]

TASK [Download /etc/.] ******************************************************************************************************************************************************************************
Password: Password: Password: Password: Password:
```

I don't have this line in the one that works What do I need to check as far as the environment set-up goes?  Have tried to remove the rsync_path, add "ansible_password" as set-fact variable - even though I cannot keep it in final version, just wanted to try it.  None of it has worked in the second environment.

Any suggestion on how to find out the actual underlying issue?

**Update 1**

I tried to run the playbook in both the environments with -vvv - one with success and other that is failing.

One thing that I observed is that with the one that is failing, just before it waits for the password 5 times, I see this 5 times.  I don't see it in the other environment

```
<localhost> EXEC /bin/sh -c 'sudo -H -S -n  -u root /bin/sh -c '"'"'echo BECOME-SUCCESS-ggiijcfnuqhoayzxutuotjsygetbbttz ; /usr/bin/python2 /export/home/svcuser/.ansible/tmp/ansible-tmp-1678303485.9-13022-128023584986366/AnsiballZ_synchronize.py'"'"' && sleep 0'
<localhost> EXEC /bin/sh -c 'sudo -H -S -n  -u root /bin/sh -c '"'"'echo BECOME-SUCCESS-dwvtzwojqsxuwbmmaadgmklcvfhsullx ; /usr/bin/python2 /export/home/svcuser/.ansible/tmp/ansible-tmp-1678303486.12-13024-43168042483626/AnsiballZ_synchronize.py'"'"' && sleep 0'
<localhost> EXEC /bin/sh -c 'sudo -H -S -n  -u root /bin/sh -c '"'"'echo BECOME-SUCCESS-zizpcfpafanjdeynuqbwwwepyfcsfxce ; /usr/bin/python2 /export/home/svcuser/.ansible/tmp/ansible-tmp-1678303486.08-13023-29940524951738/AnsiballZ_synchronize.py'"'"' && sleep 0'
<localhost> EXEC /bin/sh -c 'sudo -H -S -n  -u root /bin/sh -c '"'"'echo BECOME-SUCCESS-wsymkcfznkgheypwcicciisethkujkeh ; /usr/bin/python2 /export/home/svcuser/.ansible/tmp/ansible-tmp-1678303486.13-13025-197162246671563/AnsiballZ_synchronize.py'"'"' && sleep 0'
<localhost> EXEC /bin/sh -c 'sudo -H -S -n  -u root /bin/sh -c '"'"'echo BECOME-SUCCESS-iikkpgcjjvcjqvulmxipuluqiwywlwof ; /usr/bin/python2 /export/home/svcuser/.ansible/tmp/ansible-tmp-1678303486.15-13028-76817096913856/AnsiballZ_synchronize.py'"'"' && sleep 0'
<localhost> EXEC /bin/sh -c 'rm -f -r /export/home/svcuser/.ansible/tmp/ansible-tmp-1678303486.13-13025-197162246671563/ > /dev/null 2>&1 && sleep 0'
<localhost> EXEC /bin/sh -c 'rm -f -r /export/home/svcuser/.ansible/tmp/ansible-tmp-1678303486.08-13023-29940524951738/ > /dev/null 2>&1 && sleep 0'
<localhost> EXEC /bin/sh -c 'rm -f -r /export/home/svcuser/.ansible/tmp/ansible-tmp-1678303486.15-13028-76817096913856/ > /dev/null 2>&1 && sleep 0'
<localhost> EXEC /bin/sh -c 'rm -f -r /export/home/svcuser/.ansible/tmp/ansible-tmp-1678303486.12-13024-43168042483626/ > /dev/null 2>&1 && sleep 0'
<localhost> EXEC /bin/sh -c 'rm -f -r /export/home/svcuser/.ansible/tmp/ansible-tmp-1678303485.9-13022-128023584986366/ > /dev/null 2>&1 && sleep 0'
```

But it doesn't tell, on which servers this is happening.  What further can I check?

Comment: Where is the issue in that ~100 lines playbook? I doubt there is really no way for you to reduce it to match a [mre]?

Comment: @β.εηοιτ.βε - I have modified the question - Reduced the playbook to minimal reproducible state and added output when running it. The output has 9 servers, but i reduced the output for sample, to only two Though I am not sure, whether it is reproducible in that sense. Because , for me also, it works in one environment and not other.   And I do not know what is different in the environment that is causing the issue

Comment: Mhm since you have `rsync_path: "sudo rsync"`, verify that, on those hosts, running `sudo test` requires a password when it does not on the hosts that are working. If this is the case, this might be of interest for you: https://askubuntu.com/questions/334318/sudoers-file-enable-nopasswd-for-user-all-commands

Comment: I had manually tried on some of the hosts but also did the test `ansible -i hosts.yml all -m ping` .  I thought that if that returns a pong for all hosts from the control host, then the id has sudo access to other hosts.  Is that assumption correct?

Comment: No, you can have a passwordless connection but a password to enter on sudo'ing, as those are two totally different things (/etc/sudoers vs how sshd is configured).

Comment: Ok.  Let me try that - one possibly basic question, but I still have to ask.  Do I actually use `sudo test` or I have to use sudo with id that is running the playbook i.e. `sudo svcuser` ?

Comment: You should ssh your box with that user `ssh svcuser@server1.company.com` then try a `sudo test`; or all in one go: `ssh svcuser@server1.company.com sudo test`

Comment: I tried it on all the 9 servers and none of them asked me for a password when I ran `ssh svcuser@server1.company.com sudo test'  for all the servers.  What else can I look at ?

Comment: Do the same for a rsync command, the sudo can prompt for password or not based on the command you are using.

Comment: @β.εηοιτ.βε - I tried the rsync as you had suggested, but didn't get the issue there.  But I have updated the question with **Update 1**

Comment: The sudoers file was not set for the user in the environment that was not working.  After working with admins, getting that updated, the playbook worked